# Custom workflow how to get the execution entity

Tags: workflow, dynamics-crm-2011

This is my first custom WF for CRM 2011, and this needed to be a generic EF for any entity, I would like to know how to get the execution entity from the context or if not possible, any idea would be very nice.

I start the WF like this:

```
public class WFIntegracao: CodeActivity
    {

        protected override void Execute(CodeActivityContext context)
        {

            IWorkflowContext contexto = context.GetExtension<IWorkflowContext>();


        }
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

`IWorkflowContext` should contain the information you require.

```
IWorkflowContext contexto = context.GetExtension<IWorkflowContext>();
String entityName = contexto.PrimaryEntityName;
Guid entityId = contexto.PrimaryEntityId;
```

[MSDN IWorkflowContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xrm.sdk.workflow.iworkflowcontext_properties)

Answer (score 1):

I've not made a workflow for a entities of an unspecified type before, however you might be able to alter this code to do so; this is for a contact reference:

```cs
[RequiredArgument]
[Input("Contact")]
[ReferenceTarget("contact")]
public InArgument<EntityReference> Contact { get; set; }

protected override void Execute(CodeActivityContext context)
{
    ContactReference = Contact.Get(context);
    if (ContactReference == null)
        throw new InvalidPluginExecutionException("Contact reference is null.");

    DoSomething();
}
```

Note that I have explicitly stated that the expected input type with be a contact entity reference.  You might be able to exclude the ReferenceTarget attribute in order to lift this restriction.  You could determine the type later on by simply looking at the LogicalName member of the result of the .Get(), so in the example it'd be:

```cs
string entityType = ContactReference.LogicalName;
```

Comment: If the InArgument is <EntityReference>, the ReferenceTarget attribute is required